# Find highest number in file names on web server

Tags: php

On my webserver, I have a folder with numbered image files:

```
...
296.jpg
297.png
298.gif
...
```

The numbers are consecutive (1, 2, 3, ...). The file name contains only the number ("12.jpg", not "photo_12.jpg"). The files may not be created and stored in the order of their file name numbering (i.e. 2000.jpg might be older than 2.jpg).

I want to find the **highest number** in the file names.

I do this:

```
$glob = glob("path/to/dir/*");
$highest = max(preg_replace("|[^0-9]|", "", $glob));
// $highest is now something like 381554
```

Is there a less resource heavy method?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php readdir, got an array, order the array and take the first =)

Comment: You can also create a second array and store the filename without the extension if needed

Comment: @MarcoMura I don't understand. The only difference seems to be that the array now does not contain the path. I'd sill have to `preg_replace` (to strip file endings) and then either `max` or sort and take the first. How is that less resource heavy?

Comment: @MarcoMura The OP's solution is more optimized, since there is no need to sort an array to find the maximum. The only problem with his approach is that `glob` will return an array of all files in the directory, and the dir can contain a lot of files. In this case the only way will be to iterate over the dir file by file either with `readdir` or with `DirectoryIterator`.

Comment: why preg_replace? use a substr and array_sort

Comment: @MarcoMura I don't understand. Please post an answer with an example. Please note that numbers can be of different lengths, so `substr` might not work.

Comment: @what you do not know how to work really well with string i note. You can do a substring, putting the end to strrpos (last occurence of .) php.net -> http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php

Comment: Are your file numbers contiguous without gaps? If so, you could do a binary search testing if `filen.jpg`, then `file2n.jpg` exists which will be a whole lot quicker and less resource intensive if you have 30,000 files or so...

Comment: @MarkSetchell but won't be less heavy to save the max on creating or uploading the file on a db or into a file?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Binary search requires the array to be sorted. If it is sorted there is no need to use binary search to find the maximum.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting storing an array, just testing if `file100.jpg` exists, and if so testing if `file200.jpg` exists, then `file400.jpg`

Comment: @MarkSetchell Ahh, I got your idea. But it will require a lot of `file_exists` calls which will be even more resource heavy than the initial solution.

Comment: @MarcoMura Agreed, but it depends to a degree on how often files are added versus how often the OP needs to know how many he has. If you incur overhead on 10s of 1000s of image uploads updating the count of files but only need to know once a month how many files you have, it may be quicker to use my method.

Comment: If you care about PHP resources, than I suggest trying to call external program to do the sorting, have a look at [sort](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/04/sort-files/) utility.

Comment: @GuzAlexander Not that many - binary searches are efficient. It also depends what the resource is - if it is memory, my method will use less.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Agreed, it depends on the type of resources the OP wants to save.

Comment: The most efficient way does not sort the whole directory, using your approach to only determine the maximum number is faster. Also, you don't need an array with the whole directory content, you can also scan it linearly and only keep the highest. However, you still have to read the whole directory, which is the most expensive operation, and any operation on that data will probably be negligible, assuming that it's just a few hundreds of pictures.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you have to decide what kind of resources you want to save, because there will be different approaches depending on whether it  is memory, IO operations of something else.

So far you solution is the most optimised in terms of working speed, but it’s very memory consuming, since there may be a lot of files in the folder and you’ll hit the memory limit.

I suggest you **cache** the max somewhere, in Redis for example. And then update it every time you upload a new image.
To cache it you have to fetch it first. You can get the initial max value either with a simple script:

```
$max = 0;
foreach (new DirectoryIterator('.') as $fileInfo) {
    if ($fileInfo->isDot()) continue;

    $current = pathinfo($fileInfo->getFilename())['filename'];
    if (!is_numeric($current)) continue;
    if ($current > $max) $max = $current;
}
```

Or with a call to an external `sort` command as [vladyslav-savchenko](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27563911/519020) suggested.

Then you just have to maintain the max value updated. Update it either on every upload, by cron of both.

Answer (score 2):

This may be a working way

```
$numeric_files=glob("[0-9]*.*");
$slike = array_map(function($e){return pathinfo($e, PATHINFO_FILENAME);}, $numeric_files);
echo max($slike);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I was getting at with my comment about a binary search.

It needs no memory and takes just 0.003 seconds and 35 filechecks with 100,000 files.

I guess you could code it in PHP, or shell out to it.

```
#!/bin/bash
checkfile(){
   if [ -f "$1.jpg" ]; then
      echo DEBUG: Testing ${i}.jpg, exists - so move min marker to $1
      min=$1
      return 0
   else
      echo DEBUG: Testing ${i}.jpg, nope - so move max marker to $1
      max=$1
      return 1
   fi
}
i=1
min=0
max=-1
while : ; do
   if checkfile $i && [[ $max -eq -1 ]]; then
     ((i*=2))
   else
     ((i=(max+min)/2))
   fi
   diff=$((max-min))
   [[ $diff -eq 1 ]] && break
done
echo Result:$min
```

Output:

```
DEBUG: Testing 1.jpg, exists - so move min marker to 1
DEBUG: Testing 2.jpg, exists - so move min marker to 2
DEBUG: Testing 4.jpg, exists - so move min marker to 4
DEBUG: Testing 8.jpg, exists - so move min marker to 8
DEBUG: Testing 16.jpg, exists - so move min marker to 16
DEBUG: Testing 32.jpg, exists - so move min marker to 32
DEBUG: Testing 64.jpg, exists - so move min marker to 64
DEBUG: Testing 128.jpg, exists - so move min marker to 128
DEBUG: Testing 256.jpg, exists - so move min marker to 256
DEBUG: Testing 512.jpg, exists - so move min marker to 512
DEBUG: Testing 1024.jpg, exists - so move min marker to 1024
DEBUG: Testing 2048.jpg, exists - so move min marker to 2048
DEBUG: Testing 4096.jpg, exists - so move min marker to 4096
DEBUG: Testing 8192.jpg, exists - so move min marker to 8192
DEBUG: Testing 16384.jpg, exists - so move min marker to 16384
DEBUG: Testing 32768.jpg, exists - so move min marker to 32768
DEBUG: Testing 65536.jpg, exists - so move min marker to 65536
DEBUG: Testing 131072.jpg, nope - so move max marker to 131072
DEBUG: Testing 98304.jpg, exists - so move min marker to 98304
DEBUG: Testing 114688.jpg, nope - so move max marker to 114688
DEBUG: Testing 106496.jpg, nope - so move max marker to 106496
DEBUG: Testing 102400.jpg, nope - so move max marker to 102400
DEBUG: Testing 100352.jpg, nope - so move max marker to 100352
DEBUG: Testing 99328.jpg, exists - so move min marker to 99328
DEBUG: Testing 99840.jpg, exists - so move min marker to 99840
DEBUG: Testing 100096.jpg, nope - so move max marker to 100096
DEBUG: Testing 99968.jpg, exists - so move min marker to 99968
DEBUG: Testing 100032.jpg, nope - so move max marker to 100032
DEBUG: Testing 100000.jpg, exists - so move min marker to 100000
DEBUG: Testing 100016.jpg, nope - so move max marker to 100016
DEBUG: Testing 100008.jpg, nope - so move max marker to 100008
DEBUG: Testing 100004.jpg, nope - so move max marker to 100004
DEBUG: Testing 100002.jpg, nope - so move max marker to 100002
DEBUG: Testing 100001.jpg, nope - so move max marker to 100001
Result:100000
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting with

```
$path = "path/to/dir/";
```

Let's get an array of the file

//$myFile

```
if ($handle = opendir($path)) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
            if(!is_dir($entry)){
              $myFile[] = substr($entry,0,strrpos($entry, "."));
            }
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
```

Then we can sort the array

```
rsort($myFile,SORT_NUMERIC);
```

The first one will be the one we were searching

```
print $myFile[0];
```

This is an example and is untested.

Comment: Don't you need `SORT_NUMERIC`?

Comment: Again, you don't have to fetch the list of all files and then sort the array. Make the first as max and then compare each file to that max. You will find the max much faster and in a more efficient way.

Comment: @GuzAlexander i think that an array sort is faster then checking each element no?

Comment: Again, do not use sort for getting one maximum value. It's overkill and is not required. Plain loop (or `max`, as OP is doing) will be much faster and less memory consuming

Comment: @MarcoMura, sorting is generally not faster than a simple linear search, at least the complexity is greater. This difference between algorithms is computer science basics.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt maybe you're right. However i think that it will be better to store inside a file or inside db the last inserted file or the max one to obtain better result

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that this will result in a good solution. Especially with a large number of files what I'm assuming because of your comment that the highest number is about 381k. This will result in high I/O and maybe real performance problem when you've too much visitors and/or a slow/highly loaded server, maybe with an (older) HDD which is common for storing images.

I would recomment you to store the filenames in a database. Even if you're not using a database yet this is the best solution because you can get the highest number with a clean SQL-Query which will causing much less I/O load instead of scanning huge directorys on the filesystem. Further you can profit from indexes which will once more optimize the speed of our database-querys.

It's not neccessary to store the full path and even a bad idea when you've all files in one folder. In this case you'll produce unneccessary redundance which will waste storage and produce extra work when you maybe want to edit the path later. It's better to store only the filenames and create a constant in our config or script for the path like

```
define('IMAGE_PATH', '/var/www/images');
```

When you want to proceed with the selected image, you can do something like this:

```
$fullImagePath = IMAGE_PATH . $databaseQueryResult['fileName'];
```

I don't know what you want to do but maybe it's a good idea to think about your design when you're not using a database yet. Something in the image-hosting area looks for me like that a database can be a good idea here, also for other features you may want to implement.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
$path = 'path_to_directory';

$command = 'ls ' . escapeshellarg($path) . ' | sort -rn | head -1';

if (!($output = system($command))) {
    print 'Error during execution of: "' . $command . '"';
}

print $output;
```

Comment: No, you haven't to force 'list one file per line' with '-1' flag.

Comment: It's cleaner this way. And you need `exec`, not `system`.

Comment: You are right, `exec` is better in this case. But if we use pipes '|' after ls, it always forces 'one record per line'.